# Google Charts with different Json files

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

With all the different ways to write a Json file, I wanted to learn more about how to write them and how to use them in a Google Chart.

First I started with making and using the following Json:

```
[
{
  "Voetballer" : "Christiano Ronaldo",
  "Jaar_2010" : 79000000.00,
  "Jaar_2011" : 79700000.00,
  "Jaar_2012" : 80000000.00,
  "Jaar_2013" : 79500000.00,
  "Jaar_2014" : 80000000.00,
  "Jaar_2015" : 81000000.00
},
{
  "Voetballer" : "Lionel Messi",
  "Jaar_2010" : 55500000.00,
  "Jaar_2011" : 60000000.00,
  "Jaar_2012" : 61500000.00,
  "Jaar_2013" : 62000000.00,
  "Jaar_2014" : 63000000.00,
  "Jaar_2015" : 64700000.00
}
```

(just a part of the Json)

And I made a chart with the help of Google's chart API and the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                 
                google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                function drawChart() 
                {
                    $.getJSON('voetbal.json', function(data) 
                    {
                        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                        dataTable.addColumn('string', 'jaar');
                            $.each(data, function(key, value) 
                            {
                                dataTable.addColumn('number', value.Voetballer);
                            });
                        count=0;
                            $.each(data[0], function(key, value) 
                            {
                                if (key != "Voetballer")
                                {
                                    dataTable.addRows(1);
                                    var Year = key.split("_");
                                    dataTable.setValue(count, 0, Year[1]);
                                    count++;
                                }
                            });


                        count=1;
                            $.each(data, function(i, object) 
                            {
                                teller=0;
                                $.each(data[i], function(key, value) 
                                {
                                    if (key != "Voetballer")
                                    {
                                        dataTable.setValue(teller, count, value);
                                        teller++;
                                    }
                                });
                            count++;
                            });



                            var options = 
                            {

                            colors : ['#8bbe24','#344d59','#d1ceb2','#c95338','#fcc800','#00a0e9','#601986','#e4ebe5'],
                            title : " Top earnings ",
                            seriesType: 'bars',
                            legend: {position: 'right'},
                            series: {11: {type: 'line'}}
                            };

                            var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
                            chart.draw(dataTable, options);





                    });
                }

            </script>
```

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id="visualization"></div>
</body>
```

This chart works great!
So I wanted to move on to a different Json file, create a correct file at first which became this one:

```
[
{
    "round1": [
        {
            "playerA": 62,
            "playerB": 98,
            "playerC": 97,
            "playerD": 94,
            "playerE": 96
        }
    ]
},
{
    "round2": [
        {
            "playerA": 77,
            "playerB": 40,
            "playerC": 41,
            "playerD": 99,
            "playerE": 76
        }
    ]
}
```

(it goes on until round 10)
How ever I can't get this Json file to work using the code from my previous chart so I changed the Json a bit to this:

```
[
{
    "round": 1 [
        {
            "playerA": 62,
            "playerB": 98,
            "playerC": 97,
            "playerD": 94,
            "playerE": 96
        }
    ]
},
```

In hope that it would make it easier but all I seem to manage is a empty screen, without errors.

Hopefully there's someone out there that can either point me in the right direction or show me what I'm doing wrong, my knowledge is very slim about Json files in general. I just figured I could use the working previous code and mainly change some names and be able to use pretty much the same code.

So my question in short: How can I use the second Json file I made with Google charts? And is it easier to use the code I've already once made, or go from scratch because of the different Json file? And if so, please tell me how/point me in the right way. All this Json stuff is confusing =)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you changed the data structure of the JSON file.  The first JSON file was an Array of objects [{obj1}, {obj2}...] and the second JSON file is an ARRAY of objects that have a key with an array as a value [{obj1:[array1]},{obj2:[array2]}...].  Both are completely valid JSON formats, but the API can only render the data under the first format.  Please see this documentation to understand how you should be preparing the data for a google chart.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_preparing_data

Comment: I seem to fail getting in the second object/array, I guess my knowdledge or understanding just isn't good enough to proceed with a JSON of this format

Comment: You must pass the google api the exact format shown in the documentation.  You can store the data however you would like, but it will need to be modified prior to be passed to the google api.